# How do i find the minimum value of the following expression using AM-GM or any other well known inequality : $\frac{1}{\tan{(x)} \cdot (1-\tan^2{x})}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have the following restrictions on the expression:
$0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}$

So i could rewrite the expression as $\frac{1}{t\cdot({1-t^2})}$, such that $0<t<1$.

Is it possible to find the minimum value of the expression $\frac{1}{t\cdot({1-t^2})}$ using a famous inequality?

Comment: I don't quite know what methods you are capable of using and are allowed to use, but you can notice that if $t(1-t^2)$ is positive, you can find the maximum value of $t(1-t^2)$ instead of minimizing your expression. This is easy if you know about derivatives, and I don't know how tricky that might be at school level.

Comment: @SergeyGuminov calculus is taught in grade 11, imo

Comment: @EveryonesaysFU Your comment following my answer is very apt.  I totally overlooked the *algebra-precalculus* tag.  Therefore, I deleted my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 oh I see